# Swift parsing json read as nil

Tags: json, swift, parsing, null

So i try to parse with jsondecoder and when i see in the log menu, all the data in json is nil. While the json i check in postman all have data on it

so here's the json i want to parse (*i just want to parse the row) :

```
{
    "  user": {
    "command": "SELECT",
    "rowCount": 1,
    "oid": null,
    "rows": [
        {
            "user_id": 193,
            "u_name": "Gunawan Wibisono",
            "email": "gunwibi89@gmail.com",
            "div_name": "Design Aplication & Infrastructure",
            "url": "2"
        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "user_id",
            "tableID": 1656774,
            "columnID": 1,
            "dataTypeID": 23,
            "dataTypeSize": 4,
            "dataTypeModifier": -1,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "u_name",
            "tableID": 1656774,
            "columnID": 2,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 54,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "email",
            "tableID": 1656774,
            "columnID": 3,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 259,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "div_name",
            "tableID": 1656724,
            "columnID": 2,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 259,
            "format": "text"
        },
        {
            "name": "url",
            "tableID": 1656774,
            "columnID": 9,
            "dataTypeID": 1043,
            "dataTypeSize": -1,
            "dataTypeModifier": 259,
            "format": "text"
        }
    ],
    "_parsers": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    "_types": {
        "_types": {
            "arrayParser": {}
        },
        "text": {},
        "binary": {}
    },
    "RowCtor": null,
    "rowAsArray": false
   },
     "status": 1
 }
```

this is the code :

```
struct User : Codable {

let command : String?
let rowCount : Int?
let oid : Int?
let rows : [Rowss]?
}

struct Rowss : Codable {
let user_id: Int?
let u_name : String?
let email : String?
let div_name: String?
let url : String?

enum Codingkeys : String, CodingKey {
    case user_id = "user_id"
    case u_name = "u_name"
    case email = "email"
    case div_name = "div_name"
    case url = "url"
    }
  }


   func Json() {
    let user = UserName.text
    let pass = Password.text

    let json = "http://ratings.immobispsa.com/getslogs/\(user!)/\(pass!)"

    guard let myUrl = URL(string: json) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}

        do{
            let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
            print("this is the json\(user)")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
```

this is the log menu after i build :

"this is the jsonUser(command: nil, rowCount: nil, oid: nil, rows: nil)"

any idea where ive done wrong?

Comment: Where is your User Codable ? Can you paste all Codable structs.

Comment: Have a look into https://app.quicktype.io/ it can help you parse the JSON and provides various options that you can customize based on your needs

Comment: @Sharad Chauhan i already update the struct

Comment: @SahilManchanda i wil try to use that, thanks for the tip

Comment: This is a very good example why you should _not_ declare your properties as optional by default. If they hadn't been optional then the decoder would have generated an error that would have helped you realise your struct's were incorrect and maybe you could have fixed this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Codable` structure is wrong. You should refer some tutorials for the same. Here is the `Codable structure` as per your response:

```
struct UserResponse: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let user: User

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case user = "  user"
    }
}

struct User: Codable {
    let command: String?
    let rowCount: Int?
    let oid: Int?
    let rowCtor: Int?
    let rowAsArray: Bool?
    let rows: [Rows]?
    let fields: [Fields]?
    let parsers: [Parsers]?
    let types: Type?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case command
        case rowCount
        case oid
        case rowCtor = "RowCtor"
        case rowAsArray
        case rows
        case fields
        case parsers = "_parsers"
        case types = "_types"
    }
}

struct Rows: Codable {
    let userId: Int
    let uName: String
    let email: String
    let divName: String
    let url: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userId = "user_id"
        case uName = "u_name"
        case email
        case divName = "div_name"
        case url
    }
}

struct Fields: Codable {
    let name: String
    let tableID: Int
    let columnID: Int
    let datatypeID: Int?
    let dataTypeSize: Int
    let dataTypeModifier: Int
    let format: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case tableID
        case columnID
        case datatypeID
        case dataTypeSize
        case dataTypeModifier
        case format
    }
}

struct Parsers: Codable {

}

struct Types: Codable {
    let types: Type?
    let text: Text?
    let binary: Binary?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case types = "_types"
        case text
        case binary
    }
}

struct Type: Codable {

}

struct Text: Codable {

}

struct Binary: Codable {

}
```

If any value can come as `null`, then only mark it as `optional (?)` otherwise `don't`, and in `JSON` your user key is having extra space at the front like `"  user"`, your `API` developer should fix it if possible.

Now decode it:

```
do{
    let decodeResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserResponse.self, from: data)
    print("this is the json\(decodeResponse.user)")
}catch{
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: You should not set all properties as optional, only the ones you are really sure can be nil.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Agree, that is why I have added that point as I don't know about the response. But as there are null maybe all of them can be null or not. So I assumed that.

Comment: thanks for the answer, pardon me im still new at swift